postgresql - catch missing element when bulk inserting using unnest
I have a postgresql function, that takes multiple varchar arrays in input.
    function my_function
( 
    p_attr1                      in varchar[],
    p_attr2                      in varchar[],
    p_attr3                      in varchar[]
)

The function ingests data into a table
my_table
(
   attr1   varchar(10),
   attr2   varchar(10),
   attr3   varchar(10)
);

Each array, is expected to have the same number of elements. E.g. if p_attr1[] has 3 elements, then p_attr2[] and p_attr3[] should have 3 elements as well.
For ingestion, instead of doing a loop like
for i in 1..array_length(p_attr1, 1) loop

            insert into my_table (attr1, attr2, attr3)
            values (p_attr1[i], p_attr2[i], p_attr3[i]);
end loop;

I want to use unnest,
insert into my_table (attr1, attr2, attr3)
values (unnest(p_attr1), 
        unnest(p_attr2), 
        unnest(p_attr3)
            );  

My question is, how to catch the scenario and return an error, when one of the arrays, doesn't have the same number of elements, as the rest of the arrays?
E.g. if
p_attr1 := array['A', 'B', 'C']
p_attr2 := array['D', 'E', 'F']
p_attr3 := array['G', 'H']

I want to return an error, instead of inserting the 3rd element of p_attr3 as NULL into the table.
Thanks.

Just add NOT NULL constraint to my_table columns. create table my_table (attr1 text not null, attr2 text not null, attr3 text not null);

The problem is, those values could be NULL, they are valid. if I am getting p_attr3 := array['G', 'H', NULL] or p_attr3 := array['G', NULL, 'H'], then totally fine.
